# javafx 8 how to make choicebox look same before and after selection (no focus)

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-8

I want my choicebox to *look the same before and after a user selects something* and not have any focus indicator. Web searches indicate that I should be adjusting -fx-focus-color: and -fx-faint-focus-color: but I cannot seem to get it to act consistent. I use transparent (below) because ANY color other than transparent makes a wide glow around the choicebox after a selection.

```
default look, no css settings
```

before select:[image]
after select:[image]

```
-fx-focus-color: transparent;
-fx-faint-focus-color: transparent;
```

before select:[image]
after select:[image]

```
-fx-faint-focus-color: transparent;
```

before select:[image]
after select:[image]

```
-fx-focus-color: transparent;
```

before select:[image]
after select:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
.choice-box:focused {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-shadow-highlight-color, -fx-outer-border, -fx-inner-border, -fx-body-color;
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 -1 0, 0, 1, 2;
    -fx-background-radius: 3px, 3px, 2px, 1px;
}
```

You can see default css(= modena.css) at here: [OpenJDK/openjfx/8/master](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/707c8ea0aea2/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css).
The above code is only differences between .choice-box and .choice-box:focused.